# How can I show that $(a\gt0) \land (b\gt0) \land (b-a)(b+a)\gt0\implies (b-a\gt0) \land (b+a\gt0)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm aware that we can do this, however I'm not sure of the logical reasoning which I can use to achieve this result.

To restate the question, how I can show that:

$$(a\gt0) \land (b\gt0) \land (b-a)(b+a)\gt0$$ $$\implies (b-a\gt0) \land (b+a\gt0)$$?

I want to prove that given $a^2 \lt b^2$ that I can show that $a \lt b$, this is one of the steps which I need justification for. I'm working in the integers.

Comment: **Hint**: $(b-a)(b+a)=b^2-a^2>0$

Comment: Haha I'm actually trying to work backwards from $a^2 < b^2 \Rightarrow 0 < (b-a)(b+a)$ to show $a < b$

Comment: It's much more simple, as $x\to x^2$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the positivity of $a$ and $b$ to prove $a+b\gt0$:

$$(a\gt0) \land (b\gt0) \implies (b+a\gt0)$$

and with this and the third logical preposition supplied, we have:

$$((b-a)(b+a)\gt0) \land (b+a\gt0) \implies (b-a\gt0)$$